# Do "domain" and "set" mean the same thing in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My professor is asking me a question on my homework assignment in set theory.  First he asks me "how many equivalence relations are on a set $X$ with one element?"  Then he asks "how many equivalence relations are on a domain with two elements?"

My understanding is the word "domain" and "set" should be interchangeable.  Am I correct?

Comment: In this context you can substitute *set* for *domain*: he’s asking how many equivalence relations there are on a set with two elements. That set will necessarily be the domain of the relation. However, in general the two words are not synonymous.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: A set is (more or less) a collection of objects. The domain of a function $f$ is the collection of objects for which $f$ is defined. So, a domain is a type of set. (For example, the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is the set of nonnegative reals.)

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.  Thanks!